# Styling of Facebook LIke Button?

Tags: facebook-like, x-facebook-platform

First thing i am not sue of, is it allowed to make a custom like button, like designing a custom badge in photoshop and use it instead of the standard button. Any tips on this?

I could not find anything about the styling. For a Like Box i found the older version using "fan" instead of "like-box".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the facebook like button style is not allowed, as described in the [brand permissions page](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php) (see section "Usage" of the like button).

Honestly, that doesn't surprise me.

If you still want to proceed, [here](http://www.inboundnow.com/apps/facebook-like-button-generator/) is a custom like button generator. I did not test it, though (but you can see the html they use).